# An algorithm for solving Google Code Jam tutorial problem C

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'd like to understand the algorithm that solves [Google Code Jam, Tutorial, Problem C](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/dashboard?c=32004#s=p2). So far I wrote [my own basic implementation](https://github.com/ripper234/Basic/blob/master/java/src/main/java/org/basic/google/codejam/practicecontest/ProblemCSolver.java) that solves the small problem. I find that it's unable to deal with the large problem (complexity O(min(n, 2*k)! which is 30! in the larger data set).

I found this [solution page](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/scoreboard?c=32004#vf=1), but the solutions are of course not documented (there's a time limit to the context). I saw that at least one of the solutions used the [Union Find data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure), but I don't understand how it's applied here.

Does anyone know of a page with the algorithms that solve these problems, not just code?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there's a better way to deal with this near duplicate of [GCJ - Hamiltonian Cycles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038367/gcj-hamiltonian-cycles), but here's my answer from there:

The O(2<sup>k</sup>)-based solution uses the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). Given that there are ***k*** forbidden edges, there are ***2<sup>k</sup>*** subsets of those edges, including the set itself and the empty set. For instance, if there were 3 forbidden edges: {A, B, C}, there would be 2<sup>3</sup>=8 subsets: {}, {A}, {B}, {C}, {A,B}, {A,C}, {B,C}, {A,B,C}.

For each subset, you calculate the number of cycles that include at least all the edges in that subset . If the number of cycles containing edges ***s*** is ***f(s)*** and ***S*** is the set of all forbidden edges, then by the inclusion-exclusion principle, the number of cycles without any forbidden edges is:

```
 sum, for each subset s of S: f(s) * (-1)^|s|
```

where |***s***| is the number of elements in ***s***. Put another way, the sum of the number of cycles with any edges *minus* the number of cycles with at least 1 forbidden edge *plus* the number with at least 2 forbidden edges, ...

Calculating ***f(s)*** is not trivial -- at least I didn't find an easy way to do it. You might stop and ponder it before reading on.

To calculate ***f(s)***, start with the number of permutations of the nodes not involved with any ***s*** nodes. If there are ***m*** such nodes, there are ***m***! permutations, as you know. Call the number of permutations ***c***.

Now examine the edges in ***s*** for chains. If there are any impossible combinations, such as a node involved with 3 edges or a subcycle within ***s***, then ***f(s)*** is 0.

Otherwise, for each chain increment ***m*** by 1 and multiply ***c*** by ***2m***. (There are ***m*** places to put the chain in the existing permutations and the factor of 2 is because the chain can be forwards or backwards.) Finally, ***f(s)*** is ***c***/(***2m***). The last division converts permutations to cycles.

Answer (score 0):

The important limit imposed on the input data is that the number of forbidden edges k<=15.

You can proceed by inclusion and exclusion:

- calculate the number of all cycles ((n-1)!),
- for each forbidden edge e, substract the number of cycles that contains it ((n-2)!/2, unless n is very small),
- for each pair of forbidden edges e,f, add the number of cycles that contain both of them (this will depend on whether e and f touch),
- for each triple ..., substract ...,
- etc.

Since there are only 2^k <= 32768 subsets of F (the set of all forbidden edges), you will get a reasonable bound on the running time.

The [analysis](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/dashboard?c=32002#s=a&a=3) of the google code jam problem [Endless Knight](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/dashboard?c=32002#s=p3) uses a similar idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Hamiltonian cycle problem** is a special case of **travelling salesman problem** (obtained by setting the distance between two cities to a finite constant if they are adjacent and infinity otherwise.)

These are NP Complete problems which in simple words means **no fast solution to them is known**.

For solving questions on Google Code Jam you should know Algorimths Analysis and Design though they can be solved in exponential time and don't worry Google knows that very well. ;)

The following sources should be enough to get you started:

1. MIT Lecture Videos: "Introduction to Algorithims"
2. [TopCoder Tutorials](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=alg_index)
3. http://dustycodes.wordpress.com
4. Book: Introduction to Algorithms [Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest & Stein]
5. The Algorithm Design Manual [Steven S. Skiena]